# Can Google Hangouts send out text message under data?

Tags: google-hangouts

I found that on my android, google hangouts seems not able to send out text messages i.e. SMS to a phone number, when it is on data service.

Is it the same for others, or is it just my problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can send text messages through hangouts to phone number. For this You have to go to **`Settings > Messages > Default messaging app > Hangouts`**.